# Dynamic Query in Managed Package Salesforce

Tags: soql, managed-package

How can we write below dynamic query in managed package to pass Security review.

```
set<id> idsList=new set<id>(); // list will have ids

string query= 'select id,name,'+string.escapeSingleQuotes(selectedPhoneFiled)+' from '+string.escapeSingleQuotes(objectType)+**' where id IN : ZZZZ';**

for(sobject d:database.query(**query.replace('ZZZZ','IdsList')**)){
idVsrecord.put(d.id,d);
}
```

Comment: Explaining why this piece of code failed the security review will help people understand what you are asking.

Comment: when I run security scanner it is showing severity on "Replace"   <Line>206</Line>
          <Column>50</Column>
          <NodeId>13020</NodeId>
          <Name>replace</Name>
          <Type>replace</Type>
          <Length>7</Length>

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid replace method.

```
set<id> idsList=new set<id>(); // list will have ids

string query= 'select id, name, '+string.escapeSingleQuotes(selectedPhoneFiled)
+' from '+string.escapeSingleQuotes(objectType) +'where id IN : idsList';

for(sobject d : database.query(query)){
    idVsrecord.put(d.id, d);
}
```

Comment: To add clarity to the answer,  Dynamic Query supports bind expressions for variables within the current method. So the use of :IDsList will evaluate properly